# Editing roles from Chef web gui notworking

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Editing my role.json file from the Chef server gui apparently is not working... but using:

```
knife role edit activemq
```

Works... can somebody explain why?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what isn't working?

Comment: If I go to Policy then click on roles, then click on the role and select attributes >> edit... I edit the attributes and save them but when I run the recipe it does not find the changes... editing with knife however does work.

Comment: After you save it, try using `knife role show` to check what the object looks like?

Comment: Also editing objects via the Web UI is a really bad idea since changes will be overwritten the next time you upload from git.

Comment: I think this is a web caching issue... I'll find out for sure next week when I have access to the same chef server... thanks for your help!